# jQuery - Get mouse position while dragging link

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to track the mouse position while I click and drag an `a[href]` value to the bookmarks bar (it's for a bookmarklet). It seems to stop tracking a few seconds after I start dragging.

Code is below.

```
var isDragging = false;
$('a#dragthis')
        .mousedown(function() {
            $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
                isDragging = true;
                var x = e.pageX;
                var y = e.pageY;
                console.log(x + "|" + y);
            });
        });
```

Here is a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/GZpHP/

Comment: Can you set up a working example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Added! Thanks for checking this out.

Comment: Could you tell us why do you need the cursor postion? BTW your script will stop to work exactly in the moment you're leaving the viewport of the browser.

Comment: I want to count the pixels left for the user to drag the link to the bookmarks bar.. its fine that the script stops when it leaves the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return false` in your `mousedown` handler, to prevent the default action of selecting text upon drag.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZpHP/1/)

Comment: I want the `href` to be selected as I drag... adding `return false` seems to prevent that.

Comment: What do you mean? What are you calling "the `href`"? I don't see anything selected while you drag in your initial fiddle. If you're looking for any visual feedback, you can implement this by adding a class on your dragable when you start dragging and removining it when you finish.

Comment: The `return false` disables the ability to drag the link into your bookmarks bar. That's my main goal.

Comment: It seems that once the default drag action starts, the browser stops firing the mousemove events. I don't think this would be avoidable, but let's see if there will be other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same and ended up utilizing `ondragstart` and `ondrop` to log and then handle mouse position upon the drop event.

Its not perfect but it does the job.